# Can functions in python reference previously logged events?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Is there a way for python functions to reference previously logged events that occur within their scope or another specific function's scope?

**For example:**

Within a larger program, `process_files(files)` raises and handles an `OSError` as `logging.error(f'foo exception handled for {file} due to {bar} error')` for 4 out of 20 files, but completes the rest of the job successfully.

Later `progress_report()` will inform the user of any events of level `ERROR` or above that occurred in other functions.

**What I've Considered**

Creating my own class (below) to handle error logging and set this as a global variable. Creating a global variable `my_logger = Error_Logger()` that then can be used within every function to gather and record any errors. Other functions can then query the `errors` property or the `member_functions` property to see if another function encountered an error and check the maximum error level and number of errors encountered.

```py
class Error_Logger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.errors = {}
        
        
    @property
    def member_functions(self):
        return self.errors.keys()
    
    def log_error(self, error, level='WARNING', data=None):
        caller_name = self._caller_name()
        num_level = logging.getLevelName(level)
        if not isinstance(num_level, int):
            num_level = 0
        level_name = logging.getLevelName(num_level)
        logger = getattr(logging, str(level_name.lower()))
        logger(f'{caller_name}: {error}')
        
        if not caller_name in self.errors:
            self.errors[caller_name] = {}
        
        self.errors[caller_name].update({len(self.errors[caller_name]): 
                                             {'error': error,
                                              'level': num_level,
                                              'data': data}
                                            })
    @staticmethod
    def _error_set(errors):
        error_set = set()
        for k,v in errors.items():
            error = v.get('level', None)
            if error:
                error_set.add(error)
        return error_set
    
    def max_error(self, function=None):
        if function:
            errors = self.errors.get(function, None)
            if errors:
                max_error = max(self._error_set(errors))
            else:
                max_error = None
        else:
            errors = set()
            for k, v in self.errors.items():
                errors = errors.union(self._error_set(v))
            max_error = max(errors)
        return max_error
    

    def _caller_name(self, level=2):
        return inspect.stack()[level][3]

my_logger = Error_Logger()

def process_files(files):
    try:
        for f in files:
           stuff...
    except Exception as e:
        my_logger.log_error(f'bad things happened {e}', 'ERROR', e}

    return processed_files

def progress_report():
    if len(my_logger.errors['process_files']):
       print(f'bad things happened with {len(my_logger.errors['processed_files]}')

files = ['a', 'b', 'c']
foo = process_files(files)
progress_report()
```

**What I don't Like about This**

- I feel like I'm reinventing something that's been done better before me.
- Global variable has to be init'd first and always in the global namespace when developing other functions.
- Globals make it harder, if not impossible to export the functions from this module in the future
- [Globals are messy and can result in all sorts of unintentional changes that are hard to diagnose](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/global-variables

Comment: A dictionary that uses sequential numbers as keys should just be a list.

Comment: @Barmar: Good point. There's no reason to have a dictionary there; it would be simpler to append the values there.

Comment: Applications that want to keep a record of things like this usually use log files rather than keeping it in memory. There's a built-in Logger class that does this.

Comment: This could perhaps be implemented using a custom handler and/or filter. Perhaps review the documentation on handlers and filters to see how to achieve this, I personally can't see a need for a custom class like you've shown. Look at BufferingHandler, MemoryHandler as potential starting points for a custom handler.